# Throlling/Debouncing infinite-scroll like effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, pagination, infinite-scroll

I have a list with a pager when I am trying to add an effect that you request the next/previous page the current list is scrolled to the end/beginning. The backward scrolling is working fine, yet forward often pages multiple times, so I need to throttle/debounce it, somehow.

```
                <div className={styles.property_container} ref={scrollContainerRef} onScroll={()=> {
                  if (scrollContainerRef.current.scrollTop + scrollContainerRef.current.clientHeight > scrollContainerRef.current.scrollHeight) {
                    console.log('move pager forward');
                    throttle(handlePageClick({selected: cur + 1}), 2000);
                  } else if (scrollContainerRef.current.scrollTop === 0 && cur > 0) {
                    console.log('move pager backward');
                    handlePageClick({selected: cur - 1});
                  }
                }} >
                  {pagedListings.map((property) => (
                    <Property
                      key={property.id}
                      id={property.id}
                      price={property.original_price}
                      imgUrl={property.medium_photo_url}
                      address={property.address}
                      permalink={property.permalink}
                      bedRooms={property.total_bedrooms}
                      bathRooms={property.total_full_baths}
                      acre={property.acre}
                      handleClick={handleClick}
                    />
                  ))}
                  {!pagedListings.length && (
                    <h2 className={styles.no_result}>No Result</h2>
                  )}
                </div>
                <ReactPaginate
                  previousLabel={previousSVG}
                  nextLabel={nextSVG}
                  breakLabel="..."
                  breakClassName="break-me"
                  pageCount={pageCount}
                  marginPagesDisplayed={1}
                  pageRangeDisplayed={4}
                  containerClassName="pagination"
                  subContainerClassName="pages pagination"
                  activeClassName="active"
                  initialPage={0}
                  onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                  forcePage={cur}
                />
```

I tried throttling the onScroll effect and as in this version the thing that does the paging - `handlePageClick()`.

When I throttle/debounce the onScroll effect, it just does not page. Throttling `handlePageClick()` does nothing - it still pages multiple times.

Where/how should I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works:

```
                  onScroll={() => {
                    const margin =
                      scrollContainerRef.current.clientHeight / 4;
                    if (
                      scrollContainerRef.current.scrollTop +
                        scrollContainerRef.current.clientHeight +
                        margin >
                        scrollContainerRef.current.scrollHeight &&
                      !wait
                    ) {
                      console.log("move pager forward");
                      setWait(true);
                      handlePageClick({ selected: cur + 1 });
                    } else if (
                      scrollContainerRef.current.scrollTop === 0 &&
                      cur > 0
                    ) {
                      console.log("move pager backward");
                      handlePageClick({ selected: cur - 1 });
                    }
                  }}
```

This version includes custom-made throttling support. Somehow, the standard libraries that I tried, did not behave as wanted.